# Error in importing pdf files to excel using IE

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import some PDF files to excel using IE (open it in IE and copy-paste to excel ). My code is working for some pdf files. But for some it returns following error : "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.."

Searched many forums to resolve this, but all leads to much complicated solutions which is beyond my coding skills (still am a newbie )...
Please help.

My code:

```
Sub ImportPdf()
Dim FileName As String
Dim b2 As Workbook
Dim ie As Object
Dim np As Object
FileName="C:\somepdf.pdf"
Set b2 = ThisWorkbook
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate (FileName)

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 8)

Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4                          ' 'ERROR comes here.
    DoEvents
Loop
AppActivate ie                  

SendKeys "^(a)", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
SendKeys "^(c)", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
b2.Activate 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Sheets(1).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

The pdf files have tables, images and vary in sizes. Working file is small in size.
if I remove the Do while loop, then error comes at AppActive ie line.
Tried even removing that line, but error comes at ie.quit line.

Please also suggest if there is any easy method to import pdf to excel. (text only )

Comment: Well first of all it is no good idea to "import" PDF files. You must see PDF files exactly as a digital sheet of paper. They are like a hard print (just digital), there is almost no data structure you can use to import them properly. What can work for PDF files that were all created in the same way, will easily mess up if they are a bit different. • Second `SendKeys` is a very un-reliable method because it can be messed up with a single click by a user. • Both these facts together you need to be really lucke to get this working properly. You will very likely end up in a mess.

Comment: Instead I **highly** recommend to get the data directly from the same source the PDF was created from. Almost any format is better than extracting data from a PDF (especially if you are not the one who creates the PDF files).

Comment: What is the value of `FileName` at the time of error? try and manually open the pdf file in IE. does it open?

Comment: Yes, the desired file gets open in IE. 
As i mentioned above, the script imports text from pdf to xl ( open in IE, copy txt using sendkeys, and paste  to xl. 

issue is with some pdfs....

Comment: You can open pdfs in Word and pull the needed information via VBA to Excel. An alternate is to convert pdf online to Excel. Even possible with more than one pdf at time https://online2pdf.com/en/

Comment: Yes, i could open pdf in word and copy whole contents. There are few issues here in my scenario.The tables (there will be a many) in the PDF sometimes show as proper tables in word, whereas sometime it show as images, hence getting info from such images seems not possible. 

Can i save into *.mht or *.txt file ? (xl vba open pdf in word and save as *.mht/*.txt)
pls help with code if possible.